# How to look up a value based on a set of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column that contains a comma delimited list of users. I want to create a formula that will look at a set of unique users and return the value that matches one of the unique values in the comma delimited list. Here's an example:

[image]

Notice that User A is in both the Data column and the Look up column. User B and User C would not ever be in the look up column.

I tried using `VLOOKUP` with approximate match (TRUE), which almost works, but if two users' names are similar it can return the wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TEXTJOIN with FILTERXML:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,XLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(F2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),I:I,I:I,"",0))
```

This will return the match(es).  If only one then it will only return that one.

[image]

Comment: I like this! It has the added benefit of pulling multiple results into the same cell. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($J$2:$J$4,NOT(ISERROR(FIND($J$2:$J$4,F2)))))
```

Basically, we are filtering the lookup list to only include those items which are found in the "Data". Since this filter can potentially return more than one item (in case more than one of the Look Up names are in the Data), we use `TRANSPOSE` to pivot it and return each match on the same row:

[image]

EDIT:

To correct the point re: false positives, concatenate a comma to the lookup items and to the data:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($J$2:$J$4,NOT(ISERROR(FIND($J$2:$J$4&",",F2&",")))))
```

EDIT2:

To select only the first item, add `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($J$2:$J$4,NOT(ISERROR(FIND($J$2:$J$4&",",F2&","))))),1)
```

Comment: this will return a false positive, remove `User A` from F3 and it will still return `User A`

Comment: This is brilliant. Is there a way to return only the first match from the filter? Realistically there won't be multiple values returned, but if there are and I don't want the data to spill to the next column, is there a way to prevent that?